# how to chance the uikeyboard to the old standard cell phone numpad keyboard

Tags: iphone

I have a friend who really want to use the old keyboard that was found in older cellphones(not smartphones) that have the 1-9 keys and the ABC, DEF, etc keys with each number. Does anyone know any such project? If its jailbroken its fine also..

Comment: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no such keyboard for iPhone. I will suggest you create a custom buttons with titles as 'ABC' 'DEF' so on... as you want and assign actions to it.(i.e when you touch ABC button insert 'A' in the textfield and touching second time insert 'B'). Everything you should handle in button actions. For number keys use gesture recognizers to type when user touches screen for a long time.